# CCD document serialization error on setting EnGiven

Tags: java, jaxb, hl7, ccd

I am working on generating CCD document by marshalling generated jaxb classes. I am stuck for few days in initial portion of the document. I will try my best to explain my problem.

```
                <name>
                    <given>Henry</given>
                </name>
```

I am stuck in generating above portion of the document, to be precise the portion of generating .

I am posting all relevant jaxb classes.

```
package com.smartdatasolutions.referralmanager.ccd;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * 
 *             A name for a person. A sequence of name parts, such as
 *             given name or family name, prefix, suffix, etc. PN differs
 *             from EN because the qualifier type cannot include LS
 *             (Legal Status).
 *          
 * 
 * <p>Java class for PN complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="PN">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="{urn:hl7-org:v3}EN">
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PN")
public class PN
    extends EN
{


}






package com.smartdatasolutions.referralmanager.ccd;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRefs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMixed;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * 
 *             A name for a person, organization, place or thing. A
 *             sequence of name parts, such as given name or family
 *             name, prefix, suffix, etc. Examples for entity name
 *             values are "Jim Bob Walton, Jr.", "Health Level Seven,
 *             Inc.", "Lake Tahoe", etc. An entity name may be as simple
 *             as a character string or may consist of several entity name
 *             parts, such as, "Jim", "Bob", "Walton", and "Jr.", "Health
 *             Level Seven" and "Inc.", "Lake" and "Tahoe".
 *          
 * 
 * <p>Java class for EN complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="EN">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="{urn:hl7-org:v3}ANY">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
 *           &lt;element name="delimiter" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}en.delimiter"/>
 *           &lt;element name="family" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}en.family"/>
 *           &lt;element name="given" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}en.given"/>
 *           &lt;element name="prefix" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}en.prefix"/>
 *           &lt;element name="suffix" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}en.suffix"/>
 *         &lt;/choice>
 *         &lt;element name="validTime" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}IVL_TS" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="use" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}set_EntityNameUse" />
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "EN", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ON.class,
    PN.class,
    TN.class
})
public class EN {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "suffix", namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "delimiter", namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "given", namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "family", namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "prefix", namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "validTime", namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    })
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "use")
    protected List<String> use;

    /**
     * 
     *             A name for a person, organization, place or thing. A
     *             sequence of name parts, such as given name or family
     *             name, prefix, suffix, etc. Examples for entity name
     *             values are "Jim Bob Walton, Jr.", "Health Level Seven,
     *             Inc.", "Lake Tahoe", etc. An entity name may be as simple
     *             as a character string or may consist of several entity name
     *             parts, such as, "Jim", "Bob", "Walton", and "Jr.", "Health
     *             Level Seven" and "Inc.", "Lake" and "Tahoe".
     *          Gets the value of the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getContent().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EnSuffix }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EnDelimiter }{@code >}
     * {@link String }
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EnGiven }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EnFamily }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link EnPrefix }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link IVLTS }{@code >}
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the use property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the use property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getUse().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<String> getUse() {
        if (use == null) {
            use = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.use;
    }

}







package com.smartdatasolutions.referralmanager.ccd;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for en.given complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="en.given">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{urn:hl7-org:v3}ENXP">
 *       &lt;attribute name="partType" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}EntityNamePartType" fixed="GIV" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "en.given")
public class EnGiven
    extends ENXP
{


}









package com.smartdatasolutions.referralmanager.ccd;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * 
 *             A character string token representing a part of a name.
 *             May have a type code signifying the role of the part in
 *             the whole entity name, and a qualifier code for more detail
 *             about the name part type. Typical name parts for person
 *             names are given names, and family names, titles, etc.
 *          
 * 
 * <p>Java class for ENXP complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ENXP">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="{urn:hl7-org:v3}ST">
 *       &lt;attribute name="partType" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}EntityNamePartType" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="qualifier" type="{urn:hl7-org:v3}set_EntityNamePartQualifier" />
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ENXP")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    EnDelimiter.class,
    EnPrefix.class,
    EnSuffix.class,
    EnGiven.class,
    EnFamily.class
})
public class ENXP
    extends ST
{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "partType")
    protected String partType;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "qualifier")
    protected List<String> qualifier;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the partType property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getPartType() {
        return partType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the partType property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setPartType(String value) {
        this.partType = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the qualifier property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the qualifier property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getQualifier().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<String> getQualifier() {
        if (qualifier == null) {
            qualifier = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.qualifier;
    }

}
```

Currently i am trying this but its not working

```
        PN pn = new PN();
        EnGiven enGiven = new EnGiven();
        enGiven.setPartType("Hnery");
        pn.getContent().add(enGiven);
```

but its giving error `The method add(Serializable) in the type List<Serializable> is not applicable for the arguments (EnGiven)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using MDHT versus struggling with the JAXB code from the CDA schema
(This was a primary reason for the project)
https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/projects/mdht/

Here is a snippet of code to add a patient and patient name

```
ContinuityOfCareDocument ccd = ConsolFactory.eINSTANCE.createContinuityOfCareDocument().init();
Patient patient = CDAFactory.eINSTANCE.createPatient();
PN pn = DatatypesFactory.eINSTANCE.createPN();
pn.addText("Plain Old Name Here");
patient.getNames().add(pn);
ccd.addPatient(patient);
CDAUtil.save(ccd, System.out);
```

Here is the resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd">
  <realmCode code="US"/>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2"/>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/>
  <code code="34133-9" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Summarization of Episode Note"/>
  <confidentialityCode codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25" codeSystemName="ConfidentialityCode"/>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <patient>
        <name>Plain Old Name Here</name>
      </patient>
    </patientRole>
  </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

HTH
Sean

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `pn.getContent()` returns List of serializable objects and adding `enGiven` to the same list is throwing error because `enGiven` is not serializable. Please modify class `EnGiven` by implementing interface `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might want to use the getUse().add(newItem) method which seems to match the data type of the enGiven object.

-- My Java is rusty, My coffee is fresh.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but here is a answer for this problem.

You should use the **ObjectFactory** and use **createENGiven** method, example:

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
PN pn = new PN();
EnGiven enGiven = new EnGiven();
enGiven.setPartType("Hnery");
JAXBElement<EnGiven> jaxbeGiven = objectFactory.createENGiven(enGiven);
pn.getContent().add(jaxbeGiven);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, the mdht ipf API is perfect for this problem. I had the same issue and I used this API.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openehealth.ipf.modules/ipf-modules-cda-mdht

```
CDAR2Parser ccdaParser = new CDAR2Parser();
    ClinicalDocument clinicalDocument = ccdaParser.parse(inputStream, new Object[10]);
```